# jQuery: child-element disappears with $('.parent_class') opacity effects in IE

Tags: jquery, animation, effects, opacity

I have this html:

```
<div class="foo parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

with some css:

```
    .foo{ 
         position:absolute; 
         left: -117px;
         background:#000000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
         color:#FFFFFF;
         z-index:8;
     }
    .parent{
         top:23px;
         width:100px;
         height:30px;
         display:none;  #parent and child to start out hidden
     }
    .child{
         position:relative;
         left:94px;
         top:5px;
         height:20px;
         width: 110px;
         background:#000000;
         z-index:9;
    }
```

I want this parent and child to fade in together, and end up with opacity:0.50. Firefox does this just fine, but IE gives trouble: When I do a fadeIn() or fadeTo() or just even simply apply .css('opacity','0.50') on the parent, the parent renders and the child doesn't.

```
$('.parent').fadeTo('fast',0.50)
```

--> causes the parent to fade in but the child never appears.

```
$('.parent').fadeIn('fast')
```

--> parent appears, no child

```
$('.parent').css('opacity','0.55')
$('.parent').show()
```

--> parent appears with opacity, child never appears

```
$('.parent').show()
```

--> parent and child appear just fine (but with no animation or transparency). If I do

```
$('.parent').css('opacity','0.55') or $('.parent').fadeTo('fast', 0.50)
```

afterward, the parent gets the effect and the child *disappears*.

How can a parent and child be animated together and share opacity properties?

Comment: Are you using the newest jQuery version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some success with defining the transparency on the elements before-hand and then doing a fadeIn() on the parent element. If I do:

```
$('.child').css('opacity', '0.50');
$('.parent').css('opacity', '0.50');
$('.parent').fadeIn('fast');
```

this gives the effect I'm going for. However it's weird, I have to set the opacity on the child first. If I set them both at the same time

```
$('.child, .parent').css('opacity','0.50');
```

or if I set it on the parent first, when I do the fadeIn() the child disappears as before.

Answer (score 3):

Why not try specifying both the parent and child elements within your selector, applying the effect/css to both at the same time:

```
$('.parent, .child').fadeTo('fast',0.50);
```

Comment: good, yes this works as expected, but only if I break them up so they are siblings instead of parent and child.

I'm starting out with display:none; so it seems I need fadeIn() instead of fadeTo() (they don't appear when I do fadeTo() starting out with display:none, are they supposed to?)

$(.parent,.child').css('opacity','0.50')
$(.parent,.child').fadeIn('fast')

-->Works the way I want in IE, but only if they are siblings, otherwise if they are parent-child as above the child doesn't render. I can work with this, but I wish I could have them as parent & sibling as it helps with positioning.

Comment: On closer examination, I really need them to be parent-sibling. It's annoying, I've tried many different configurations of classes, locators, jquery methods. It seems as soon as I give the parent transparency, with .css or .fadeIn() or .fadeTo(), the child disappears and can't be re-rendered. It no longer responds to .show() or .css('display','block'), etc. This happens if I apply the effect to the parent or to both simultaneously  as suggested. If the effect is applied to the parent at all, the child disappears.